# How to set selector of NSButton (IB)

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder

How do I set the selector (so which method will be called when the button is pressed), of an NSButton in Interface Builder, I have created an IBAction method and declaration, but it doesn't show in IB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure a) The object is of the right class, and b) You put the IBAction in the header file and saved it.

If you have done that and it still doesn't show up, go to File->Reload All Class Files in IB.

Answer (score 0):

You connect the selector outlet of the button to the object in the nib file whose class declares the IBAction (right-click & drag), and then select the action from the list that pops up.

Comment: The inaction doesn't appear in the list. I have done this many times when programming for iPhone.